# Não consigo ler coluna no pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Eu tenho esse Dataframe:

```
             Nome          CPF      ...        Senha          Cargo
0     Silvio José  10575674451      ...        12345  Administrador
1  Carlos Alberto  10767764330      ...        12345  Administrador
2  Maria Madalena  23323234343      ...        12345     Supervisor
3    Caio Bezerra  10992329221      ...        12345     Supervisor
4  Mateus Alencar  10732393213      ...        12345     Supervisor
```

Quando utilizo esse comando `pessoas_frame['CPF']` ele imprime a coluna normalmente. Mas quando utilizo o comando `pessoas_frame['Idade']` ele manda uma mensagem: `KeyError: 'Idade'`

Agora se eu usar o comando `pessoas_frame.iloc[:, 2]` ele imprime a coluna normalmente:

```
0    23
1    21
2    20
3    23
4    22
Name: Idade , dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não sei de onde você tirou essas colunas, mas parece que a coluna do seu dataframe está com o nome de `'Idade '` e não `'Idade'`.

Tente utilizar o comando:

```
pessoas_frame['Idade ']
```